How can I get rpy2 to successfully install or access the tidyverse within Linux?
I am attempting to use the tidyverse within rpy2 (version 3.5.16) on my Linux Mint computer. I figure that there are two potential ways to accomplish this task: (1) Using the tidyverse installation that already works within the R console and RStudio, or (2) importing the tidyverse within rpy2. My preference is to use the first option so that I can apply the same set of packages for tasks within R and Rpy2.
Option 1: Importing pre-existing tidyverse package
I had used sudo apt install r-base r-cran-tidyverse to install the tidyverse within my computer. I believe this install worked correctly, as the following code does not raise any errors within my R console and RStudio:
library(tidyverse)
However, running the following Python code within a Jupyter notebook fails:
import rpy2
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
utils = importr('utils')
survey = importr('survey')
srvyr = importr('srvyr')

Error message:
PackageNotInstalledError: The R package "tidyverse" is not installed.
Is there a way that I can point Rpy2 to my existing tidyverse installation?
Option 2: Installing a new copy of the tidyverse using rpy2
This option is also failing for me. I tried running the following Python script:
import rpy2
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
# import R's "base" package
base = importr('base')

# import R's "utils" package
utils = importr('utils')
utils.install_packages('tidyverse')
print("Done!")

However, a few minutes into the installation process, this error message appeared:
ERROR: dependencies ‘conflicted’, ‘ragg’, ‘reprex’ are not available for package ‘tidyverse’
* removing ‘/home/myusername/miniforge3/envs/myenv/lib/R/library/tidyverse’

I thought I could resolve this issue by installing the packages individually, but when I ran utils.install_packages('conflicted'), I then got the following message:
ERROR: dependency ‘memoise’ is not available for package ‘conflicted’
I could try to manually install memoise also, but I figure that that package, in turn, might depend on another missing package. Is there an easier way to automatically install these missing packages?

I kept running into error messages when attempting to compile the tidyverse for Linux. I also tried to use r2u to install the tidyverse, but I wasn't able to get its setup script to run (possibly due to conflicts with my pre-existing R installation). Therefore, I instead tried to install each tidyverse package individually. This approach appears to have worked, as each of the following lines ran successfully:
utils.install_packages('dplyr')
utils.install_packages('tidyr')
utils.install_packages('readr')
utils.install_packages('ggplot2')
utils.install_packages('tibble')
utils.install_packages('stringr')
utils.install_packages('forcats')
utils.install_packages('lubridate')

In addition, I am also able to run the following cell without any issues:
dplyr = importr('dplyr')
tidyr = importr('tidyr')
readr = importr('readr')
ggplot2 = importr('ggplot2')
tibble = importr('tibble')
stringr = importr('stringr')
forcats = importr('forcats')
lubridate = importr('lubridate')

